# Python: How to find a window of unique characters in a string

Tags: python

The objective of the part 2 for advent of code 2022 day 6:
You are given an input string. You need to return the amount of characters that need to be processed before the 'first start-of-message marker' is detected.

A start of message marker is the index of the last character in a unique subset of length 14 found in the input.

For example, if we are looking for a substring of length `3` and as input `abababc` we should get `6` because when `c` appears, we have `abc` which is the first substring of length `3`.

I have completed part 2 for advent of code 2022 day 6, however I tried to make it more efficient by doing this:

```
def part2V2(inputLine):
    INPUT_LINE = inputLine.strip()
    chars = [False] * 26
    OFFSET = ord('a')
    LENGTH = len(INPUT_LINE)

    i = 0

    for j in range(LENGTH):
        index = ord(INPUT_LINE[j]) - OFFSET

        if chars[index] == False:
            chars[index] = True

            if j-i == 13: #13 since we are looking for 14 unique characters minus 1 for the index
                return j
        else:
            chars = [False] * 26
            chars[index] = True
            i = j
```

As you can probably guess, this does not work, and I am not sure why.

Suppose we give the input:

```
'abababc'
```

The answer that I expect for a window of size `3` would be `6` and that is exactly what I get, however for my real input the function returns `None`

Comment: It would be helpful if you described the advent of code 2022 part 2 problem as part of your question.  Also, please explain what you mean by " I expect for a window of size 3 would be 6 and that is exactly what I get, however for my real input the function returns "  You either get the right answer or you don't why do you say you get the right answer but you return None?

Comment: "for my real input the function returns ```None```" This means that it runs as expected for the supposed input above, but not for my real input. Also, I will add context to the question above.

Comment: what is your "real input" string?

Comment: Here's the problem with your thinking.  When you find a duplicate, you reset the "start of string" to that spot.  However, that character might actually be in the MIDDLE of the target string.  Look at the second sample line ("bvwbjplbg...").  There's a g at position 9 and 17, but the "g" in 17 is in the middle of the unique sequence, which ends at 23.

Comment: I understand, so in this case, instead of setting the 'start of string' `i` to the `g` at position 17, I will set it to the first occurrence of `g` in the substring which is position 9.

Comment: My real input: https://github.com/EduardCostache/advent-of-code-2022/blob/main/Day%206/input.txt

Expected Output = 2980

Comment: Sharing your original solution would be useful, so we can see what efficiency you're trying to improve from.